# Why does the output of the code changes, when printing a random text with printf?

Tags: c, string, printf, cs50

The following code changes the letters of the input by k. k is the first argument. For example, if the input should be changed by 2 letters the command line argument would be "./caesar 2", if three then "./caesar 3". etc.
Changing letters means, for example, change by 2, then input 'a' becomes 'c'. Change by 3 means input "abc" becomes "def", etc.
The input provided by the user is being checked if (a) the number arguments is exact 2, (b) the argument is a number.

The code executed as the code is written below the output is shortened by one letter. For example, "hello" changed by 1 letter becomes "iffm".
If one letter is entered only,  it shows the correct output follwed by some undefined letters. For example, 'a' becomes "b��P" or "bm>�" or "b;���".

When either (1) the input check (b) [if the argument is a number] is removed OR (2) a printf line with a random statement (it can even be an empty string) is inserted EXACTLY between the get_string function, when asking the user for input and the for-loop, when changing the letters the output is as intended. Or (3) if the input's last character is a special character, the output is as expected (special character is any non-alphabetical character). for example, "hello1" or "hello!" changed by one letter becomes "ifmmp1" or "ifmmp!".

I am really desperate and I don't know what is happening and more importantly why this is happening.
So my questions are:
(1) Why is output shortened by one letter? Why is the output wrong, when the input is one letter only? (I guess it's the same problem).
(2)
(a) Why does the output change when either the number check is removed or 
(b) a random printf line is inserted exactly between the lines mentioned above or
(c) the last character is a non-alphabetical character?

I really appreciate any help and please excuse any weird English as it is not my native language :). Thanks a lot! A desperate code learner :)

This is the code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

bool isNumber(string numberToCheck);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // checking, if arguments are correct
    // checking, if input is correct (i.e. 2)
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./cesar key\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // checking, if input is a number, if the following if statement is removed the output changes
    if(!isNumber(argv[1]))
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // variables
    int k = atoi(argv[1]);
    string plaintext;
    int plaintextLength;

    // getting the plaintext from user input, creating ciphertext string of same length
    plaintext = get_string("paintext: ");

    // checking the length of the input
    plaintextLength = strlen(plaintext);

    //the output changes, when the next line is being inserted
    printf("");

    // creating new empty string with plaintextLength
    char ciphertext[plaintextLength];

    // iterating through plaintext char by char
    for(int i = 0; i < plaintextLength;i++)
    {
        // in case of capital letter
        if(plaintext[i] >= 65 && plaintext[i] <= 90)
        {
            ciphertext[i] = 65 + (((plaintext[i] - 65) + k) % 26);
        } 
        // else in case of small letter
        else if(plaintext[i] >= 97 && plaintext[i] <= 122)
        {
            ciphertext[i] = 97 + (((plaintext[i] - 97) + k) % 26);
        }
        // else in case of non alphabetical letter
        else
        {
            ciphertext[i] = plaintext[i];
        }
    }
    printf("ciphertext: %s\n", ciphertext);
}

bool isNumber(string numberToCheck)
{
    for(int i = 0;i < strlen(numberToCheck); i++)
        {
            if(!isdigit(numberToCheck[i]))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You're not 0-terminating a string.

Comment: Show us `get_string`.

Comment: `plaintextLength` is the length of the string, meaning the number of characters in the string not counting the null terminator.  That means `ciphertext[plaintextLength]` does not have room for the null terminator at the end that is required for C strings.  You need to add 1 extra location for the null terminator and set the contents of that location to 0.

Comment: Tje correct encipherment to `hello` is `ifmmp` and not `iffm`, as you state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    int i;
    // iterating through plaintext char by char
    for(i = 0; i < plaintextLength;i++)
    {
        // in case of capital letter
        if(plaintext[i] >= 65 && plaintext[i] <= 90)
        {
            ciphertext[i] = 65 + (((plaintext[i] - 65) + k) % 26);
        } 
        // else in case of small letter
        else if(plaintext[i] >= 97 && plaintext[i] <= 122)
        {
            ciphertext[i] = 97 + (((plaintext[i] - 97) + k) % 26);
        }
        // else in case of non alphabetical letter
        else
        {
            ciphertext[i] = plaintext[i];
        }
    }
    ciphertext[i] = '\0';
    printf("ciphertext: %s\n", ciphertext);
}
```

**In C every string uses \0 to tell the computer that it has reached the end of a string.**

Without this NULL terminating operator, the computer might try to read past the string into the memory, that is why you encounter random symbols.

So when you are creating a string make sure to add \0 at the end of it, this is what I did with your code here.
I declared "i" outside the for loop the it doesn't cease to exist at the end of the loop.
When you reach the end of the loop, "i" will be equal to the length of your string.

If my plaintext is "lol" and the key is 5, "i" will be equal to 3 and the ciphertext will be "qtq".
Ciphertext[i] will point just after the last "q" since we count from 0 an this is where you want to put your \0.

Also there is a typo in your getstring.

Hope my explaination is clear, if you have any question juste ask :)